# How to fix Private Internet Access' kill switch?

Tags: vpn, dns, internet

When you enable Private Internet Access' kill switch, you can only have internet when you are connected to the VPN. When you disable it, you should have internet even if the VPN is not enabled.

[image: Private Internet Access Kill Switch]

#### The problem

Although I disabled the kill switch, I only have internet access when I am connected to the VPN. This seems like a bug on PIA's side, but how can I make my internet work again on my Mac (without needing to be connected to VPN)?

Answer (score 1):

When you enable the Kill Switch, PIA changes some config which apparently wasn't reverted when disabling the Kill Switch. PIA also warns you for this:

[image: VPN Kill Switch warning]

What you can do is manually revert the changes made by PIA. Running the following commands in your terminal should work:

1. Check the status

   ```
   sudo pfctl -a com.privateinternetaccess -s rules
   ```

   > No ALTQ support in kernel
   >   ALTQ related functions disabled
   >   pass in quick on ! utun2 inet from 10.0.0.0/8 to any no state
   >   pass in quick on ! utun2 inet from 172.16.0.0/12 to any no state
   >   pass in quick on ! utun2 inet from 192.168.0.0/16 to any no state
   >   pass in quick on lo0 all no state
   >   block drop in on ! utun2 inet from ! 46.166.137.225 to any
2. Flush/revert change by PIA

   ```
   sudo pfctl -a com.privateinternetaccess -s rules
   ```

   > No ALTQ support in kernel
   >   ALTQ related functions disabled

And also reset your DNS (`Open Network Preferences > Wi-Fi > Advanced... > DNS`). It should work without restarting your Mac or anything else.